# What is the value of $\frac{a^2}{b+c} + \frac{b^2}{a+c} + \frac{c^2}{a+b}$ if $\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b} = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b} = 1$$ then find the values of $$\frac{a^2}{b+c} + \frac{b^2}{a+c} + \frac{c^2}{a+b}.$$ How can I solve it? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}=1$, what can we say about $\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{c+a}+\frac{c^2}{a+b}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901062/if-fracabc-fracbca-fraccab-1-what-can-we-say-about-fraca)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{a^2}{b+c}+a=\dfrac{a(a+b+c)}{b+c}$$

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(\dfrac{a^2}{b+c}+a\right)=(a+b+c)\sum_{\text{cyc}}\dfrac a{b+c}$$

Comment: the required answer is 0.Isn't it?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay., It seems $$a+b+c-(a+b+c)$$

Answer (score 6):

You have $$a+b+c = (a+b+c)\left(\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\right) = \frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{a+c}+\frac{c^2}{a+b} + a+b+c.$$

Then you get $$\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{a+c}+\frac{c^2}{a+b} = 0.$$